# Nest can't resolve dependencies although module is exported and imported Nestjs

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have 2 modules

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]),
    forwardRef(() => FriendModule),
    forwardRef(() => RequestFriendModule),
  ],
  providers: [UserService],
  controllers: [UserController],
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}

@Module({
  controllers: [NotificationController],
  providers: [NotificationService],
  imports: [UserModule],
  exports: [NotificationService],
})
export class NotificationModule {}
```

In my `notification.service`:

```
 constructor(
    private readonly userService: UserService,
 )
```

And i got error: `Nest can't resolve dependencies of the NotificationService (?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the NotificationModule context`

I exported `UserService` in `UserModule`, then import `UserModule` in `NotificationModule`.

Why this happen? And how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you can see in the docs [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/common-errors#cannot-resolve-dependency-error), since you have 'dependency at index ..', that's because you got a circular dependency.

You can learn more about them here: [Circular Dependencies in NestJS and how to Avoid Them](https://trilon.io/blog/avoiding-circular-dependencies-in-nestjs)